# How to set VLC to pause payback when headphones are disconnected?

Tags: vlc-media-player

When using VLC and I disconnect my headphones, VLC does not pause the audio and continues playing from speakers. Using other players (Windows Media Player), the audio would stop when the audio device changes.

What I expected is that when I turn my headphones off (or any other device, wireless or not) playback would pause and would not come out through my speakers (the default device with out headphones).

I found a [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/642898/) which uses a script but I would prefer to change the settings of VLC instead of scripts and also I am not on Linux.

Comment: Given your wanting this to be a function of VLC settings, the first question would be: have you reviewed the VLC settings to see if this is an available feature? If it isn't, a script may be your only option, or some sort of "helper" app such as AutoHotKey, that can respond to system events and send signals as a result.